# Apache Flink 1.11 Streaming Sink to S3

Tags: apache-flink, minio, flink-sql, pyflink, flink-table-api

I'm using the Flink FileSystem SQL Connector to read events from Kafka and write to S3(Using MinIo). Here is my code,

```
exec_env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.get_execution_environment()
exec_env.set_parallelism(1)
# start a checkpoint every 10 s
exec_env.enable_checkpointing(10000)
exec_env.set_state_backend(FsStateBackend("s3://test-bucket/checkpoints/"))
t_config = TableConfig()
t_env = StreamTableEnvironment.create(exec_env, t_config)

INPUT_TABLE = "source"
INPUT_TOPIC = "Rides"
LOCAL_KAFKA = 'kafka:9092'
OUTPUT_TABLE = "sink"

ddl_source = f"""
       CREATE TABLE {INPUT_TABLE} (
           `rideId` BIGINT,
           `isStart` BOOLEAN,
           `eventTime` STRING,
           `lon` FLOAT,
           `lat` FLOAT,
           `psgCnt` INTEGER,
           `taxiId` BIGINT
       ) WITH (
           'connector' = 'kafka',
           'topic' = '{INPUT_TOPIC}',
           'properties.bootstrap.servers' = '{LOCAL_KAFKA}',
           'format' = 'json'
       )
   """

ddl_sink = f"""
       CREATE TABLE {OUTPUT_TABLE} (
           `rideId` BIGINT,
           `isStart` BOOLEAN,
           `eventTime` STRING,
           `lon` FLOAT,
           `lat` FLOAT,
           `psgCnt` INTEGER,
           `taxiId` BIGINT
       ) WITH (
           'connector' = 'filesystem',
           'path' = 's3://test-bucket/kafka_output',
           'format' = 'parquet'
       )
   """

t_env.sql_update(ddl_source)
t_env.sql_update(ddl_sink)

t_env.execute_sql(f"""
    INSERT INTO {OUTPUT_TABLE}
    SELECT * 
    FROM {INPUT_TABLE}
""")
```

I'm using Flink 1.11.3 and flink-s3-fs-hadoop 1.11.3. I have copied the flink-s3-fs-hadoop-1.11.3.jar into the plugins folder.

```
cp /opt/flink/lib/flink-s3-fs-hadoop-1.11.3.jar /opt/flink/plugins/s3-fs-hadoop/;
```

Also I have added the following configs into the flink-conf.yaml.

```
    state.backend: filesystem
    state.checkpoints.dir: s3://test-bucket/checkpoints/
    s3.endpoint: http://127.0.0.1:9000
    s3.path.style.access: true
    s3.access-key: minio
    s3.secret-key: minio123
```

MinIo is running properly and I have created the 'test-bucket' in MinIo. When I run this job the job submission doesn't happen and Flink Dashboard goes to a some sort of waiting state. After 15-20 mins I get the following exception,

```
pyflink.util.exceptions.TableException: Failed to execute sql
```

What seems to be the problem here?

Comment: How are you starting the cluster, and how are you submitting the job? What do you see in the log files?